# Use first digit as factor to standardize values in R

Tags: r

I have large data frame `tocalculate` from a survey (original data frame `brfss2013` where one of the variables represents the number of times a person checks blood glucose levels. The data is in 3 digits:

First digit tells you if the measurements are per day (1), per week (2), per month (3)or per year (4). The second and third digits represent the actual value.

Example: 101 is once ( _01) per day (1 _ _), 202 is twice per week, etc.

I want to standardize everything to get value of times per year. So I will multiply the 2nd and 3rd digits by 365, 52.143, 12 and 1 (days, weeks, months, year).

I think I would be able to "select" the digits to use, but I'm not sure how to write something that can work with different rows with different set of instructions.

EDIT:

Adding my attempt and sample data.

```
tocalculate <- brfss2013 %>%
  filter(nchar(bldsugar) > 2)

bldsugar2 <- sapply(tocalculate$bldsugar, function(x) {
  if (substr(x,1,1) == 1) {x*365}
  if (substr(x,1,1) == 2) {x*52}
  if (substr(x,1,1) == 3) {x*12}
  if (substr(x,1,1) == 4) {x*365}
})
```

I'm getting a lot of NULL values though...

Comment: Please provide some explicit sample data and show your attempt so far. It sounds like you could use `factor` with a custom `labels` argument for each digit, then `paste` it all together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using `dplyr`, `recode` is a handy function. I use `%/%` to see how many times 100 goes in to each `bldsugar` value and `%%` to get the remainder when divided by 100.

```
# sample data
brfss_sample = data.frame(bldsugar = c(101, 102, 201, 202, 301, 302, 401, 402))

library(dplyr)
mutate(
    brfss_sample,
    mult = recode(
        bldsugar %/% 100,
        `1` = 365.25,
        `2` = 52.143,
        `3` = 12,
        `4` = 1
    ),
    checks_per_year = bldsugar %% 100 * mult
)
#   bldsugar    mult checks_per_year
# 1      101 365.250         365.250
# 2      102 365.250         730.500
# 3      201  52.143          52.143
# 4      202  52.143         104.286
# 5      301  12.000          12.000
# 6      302  12.000          24.000
# 7      401   1.000           1.000
# 8      402   1.000           2.000
```

You could, of course, remove the `mult` column (or combine the definitions so it is never created in the first place).

Comment: I liked that you added 0.25 to my 365 days in a year, your solution works great

Comment: Ha! I thought you had the `.25`. I assumed you had it because I remembered you had the 52.143.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Data
set.seed(42)
x = sample(101:499, 100, replace = TRUE)
#1st digit
as.factor(floor((x/100)))
#Values
((x/100) %% 1) * 100
```

Comment: This looks great, but I'm not sure I understand how `floor()` works even after reading the documentation, so I'm not sure I can implement it correctly

Comment: I think I got it... Basically it is used to give you "round down" your fraction?

Comment: @jesusgarciab yes - `floor` rounds down, `ceiling` round up, and `trunc` rounds toward 0. (`trunc` is the same as `floor` for positive numbers, the same as `ceiling` for negative numbers). And of course `round` goes to the nearest.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first thing you can do is to split the 3-digit variable into two variables. The first variable is only one digit, which shows sampling frequency; and the second variable shows times of measurement.

In R, `substr` or `substring` can select the string by specifying the first and last position to subset.

```
# Create example data frame
ex_data <- data.frame(var = c("101", "202", "204"))

# Split the variable to create two new columns
ex_data$var1 <- substring(ex_data$var, first = 1, last = 1)
ex_data$var2 <- substring(ex_data$var, first = 2, last = 3)

# Remove the original variable
ex_data$var <- NULL
```

After this, you can manipulate your data frame. Perhaps convert `var1` to factor and `var2` to numeric for further manipulation and analysis.